# Constant garbage collection Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I check my application log and see the following:

```
163.029: [GC163.029: [ParNew: 545354K->8K(613440K), 0.0421560 secs] 547578K->2232K(20903424K), 0.0422630 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.03, real=0.04 secs]
164.014: [GC164.014: [ParNew: 545352K->6K(613440K), 0.0438010 secs] 547576K->2230K(20903424K), 0.0439220 secs] [Times: user=0.30 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
164.995: [GC164.996: [ParNew: 545350K->10K(613440K), 0.0350310 secs] 547574K->2234K(20903424K), 0.0351570 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
165.967: [GC165.967: [ParNew: 545354K->8K(613440K), 0.0532350 secs] 547578K->2232K(20903424K), 0.0533560 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
166.946: [GC166.946: [ParNew: 545352K->10K(613440K), 0.0308930 secs] 547576K->2234K(20903424K), 0.0309980 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
167.919: [GC167.919: [ParNew: 545354K->12K(613440K), 0.0393180 secs] 547578K->2236K(20903424K), 0.0394180 secs] [Times: user=0.30 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
168.890: [GC168.890: [ParNew: 545356K->4K(613440K), 0.0449310 secs] 547580K->2230K(20903424K), 0.0450500 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
169.869: [GC169.869: [ParNew: 545348K->4K(613440K), 0.0422740 secs] 547574K->2230K(20903424K), 0.0423800 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.02, real=0.04 secs]
170.850: [GC170.850: [ParNew: 545348K->4K(613440K), 0.0434500 secs] 547574K->2230K(20903424K), 0.0435570 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

There's plenty enough memory (I'm using only 2.6% memory available)

What could possibly cause such behaviour? I'm using this command

```
     java -Xss515m -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -jar
```

Comment: This --> -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps

Comment: Also, do you really want to set the initial memory allocation pool to 20GB?

Comment: For 20gb heap, your young generation of 600mb is way too low.

Answer (score 1):

Given that HotSpot uses a [ephemeral GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29), common garbage collection is normal and harmless. That just means that the eden generation has run out of space and is being collected, which is normally very fast -- pretty much unnoticeable.

The frequency of garbage collection, therefore, is mostly related to your allocation *bandwidth*, rather than the amount of memory "in use". The mistake is in thinking it's something bad, while in fact it is how the GC is designed and intended to work.

Answer (score 1):

All modern Java GC's have generational structure.

If you use Oracle Hotspot then you have: Young generation, Old generation and depending of the GC version it's PermGen (till 7 ver.) or Metaspace(8 ver.)

Young generation usually smaller than the old one, because its collection should be finished quickly.

If you want to decrease the number of minor collections than set *-Xmn* param to a bigger value 
(e.g. *-Xmn1G*).